# How to prevent Screenshots & Screen Recording in a flutter desktop application

Tags: flutter, dart, desktop-application

I want to prevent user from taking screenshots and screenrecording

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```
FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are almost unlimited alternatives to record a desktop screen, I doubt that you will find any effective solution to prevent desktop users recording your application.